# Angular async validators 'updateOn' and Specific Condition

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

I am trying to get a async validator to only fire onblur and if a boolean is true.

I thought I would be able to get it to work by converting the the updateOn args to an array and adding in a second object like so:

```
this.createOrganisation.addControl('address', this.ofb.group(
        {                
            addressPostcode: [null, { validators: [Validators.required], asyncValidators: [this.postCodeValidator], updateOn: [ 'blur', this.showAlert] }]

        }   
    ));
```

btw:

```
this.showAlert
```

is set to false.

Anyone got any ideas how to only validate on blur and if that boolean is set to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`updateOn` only accepts `'change' | 'blur' | 'submit'` strings and should work on only those events, you can not make it work by making it an array.

As far as I understand, the deciding factor of the added validators in your case is the `showAlert` flag. If only `showAlert` is true only then we need to check whether to do a validation on a `blur` event or not. If this assumption is true and you don't update the `showAlert` flag during a `blur` event then you can use this approach.

I am setting the form controls with and without validators depending on the `showAlert` flag status. Have its setter/getter like:

```
set showAlert(val) {
    this._showAlert = val
    this._modifyControl()
}

get showAlert() {
  return this._showAlert
}

private _modifyControl() {
  if (this.showAlert) {
    if (this.createOrganisation.get('addressPostcode')) {
      let controlValue = this.createOrganisation.get('addressPostcode').value
      this.createOrganisation.setControl('addressPostcode', new FormControl(controlValue, { validators: [Validators.required], asyncValidators: [this.postCodeValidator.bind(this)], updateOn: 'blur' }))
    }
    else {
      this.createOrganisation.addControl('addressPostcode', new FormControl(null, { validators: [Validators.required], asyncValidators: [this.postCodeValidator.bind(this)], updateOn: 'blur' }))
    }
    
  }
  else {
    if (this.createOrganisation.get('addressPostcode')) {
      let controlValue = this.createOrganisation.get('addressPostcode').value
      this.createOrganisation.setControl('addressPostcode', new FormControl(controlValue))
    } else {
      this.createOrganisation.addControl('addressPostcode', new FormControl(null))
    }
    
  }
}
```

you can use this if it suits your requirements.

Caution:

1. Don't update the flag in a blur event.
2. If the flag is updated while a user is typing in the input box then he will loose focus from the input as the control will be updated.

See an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/updateoncontrol?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

I would look at this a bit differently... have the async validator be "valid" if the boolean prop is `false`. So something like this:

```
... asyncValidators: [this.postCodeValidator.bind(this)], updateOn: 'blur' ...
```

Binding `this` to get the value of the boolean you are using, to get the correct `this`.

Then the async validator, apply to your usecase:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

// ....

postCodeValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
  if (!this.showAlert) { 
    return of(null)
  } else {
    // do your stuff...
  }
}
```